# Format is not working in an old SQL Server version

Tags: sql-server, format, type-conversion, sql-convert

I am using format in a stored procedure. My problem is that on the server the SQL Server version is old, and `format()` does not work.
My use:

```
FORMAT([Data], 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

where data is: `2008-10-31 00:00:00.000`

How can I use `convert()` to obtain the same result?

Comment: What are the exact version(s) of SQL Server you're dealing with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the format mysteriously called "104".  You can use:

```
select convert(varchar(10), data, 104)
```

The mysteries of the format codes are explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

You can use this in any version of SQL Server.  `format()` is much saner but only available since SQL Server 2012.